# Почему регулярные в Перл быстрее на 40%, чем в Go?

Tags: golang, perl

Почему регулярные в Перл быстрее на 40%, чем в Go? Часть простого скрипта анализа лога.

Perl:

```
       $l=~s/\A([^\s]+?) - - \[([^\]]+?)\] \"([^\"]+?)\" ([^\s]+?) ([^\s]+?) \"([^\"]+?)\"(.+)/$1\n$2\n$3\n$4\n$5\n$6\n$7/g;
       ($ip, $time, $page, $code, $size, $ref, $agent, $els) = split(/\n/, $l);
       $page=~s/(GET|HEAD|POST) (.+) (HTTP.+)/$2/;
       $hash{$page}++;
       # this faster than Golang (35-40%)
```

Go:

```
    log_format := `^([^ ]+) (-) (-) \[([^\]]+)\] "([^\"]+?)" ([0-9]+) ([^ ]+) "([^"])*" "([^"]*)"`
    logParser := regexp.MustCompilePOSIX(log_format)
    log_format_get := `^(GET|HEAD|POST) (.+) (HTTP.+)$`
    logParserGet := regexp.MustCompilePOSIX(log_format_get)
    var hash = make(map[string] int);

    analize1 := func (iline *string) {
    submatch := logParser.FindSubmatch(strings.TrimSpace(*iline))
    if (len(submatch[0])>0){
        pg := logParserGet.FindAllStringSubmatch(strings.TrimSpace(submatch[0][5]), 1)
        if (len(pg)>0){
                hash[pg[0][2]]++
        }
    }
```

Comment: У вас на Go в "циклическом" методе `FindSubmatch` и `FindAllStringSubmatch` вставляется скриптовая команда `TrimSpace`, что может вызывать значительное замедление, в сравнении с `split`, который не генерирует цикл с вложеной скриптовой командой. Старайтесь не делать скриптовые циклы если хотите выиграть время. Может как-то можно разделить без вложений поправив выражение regex или как-то по-другому что б цикл обрабатовало ядро, а не скрипт - тогда будет быстрее.

Comment: 1) Сначала постройте корректные профилировочные тесты, исключающие влияние всего остального, потом уже сравнивайте 2) Само по себе название Perl о чём-то говорит?

Comment: TrimSpace не влияет на скорость.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще везде пишут, что оптимизация регулярных выражений в языке Go выполнена хуже, по сравнению с Perl, потому что Perl постарше и в его разработку было вложено больше человек/часов.

Вот тут есть тест скорости в разных языках,
[image: тест скорости регулярных выражений]

Comment: Какая-то неправильная диаграмма. Ну и обезличенная. 1) В ней отсутствует php- он бы занял лидирующие места, после перла 2) перл обрабатывает регулярные выражения быстрее v8/js, проверено 3) перл не так сильно отличается от С, ибо сам модуль pcre представлен нативным кодом. А вообще- да. Все зависит от качества оптимизации самого движка в конкретном взятом языке.

Comment: @PeterSmith ты прав)

Comment: Нашел оригинал по картинке -_- http://citforum.ru/news/26547/ какой-то черный ящик тестировали :)

Comment: @ReinRaus  я на английском читал)