# Поиск и подсчёт частично совпадающих строк во всех файлах

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, perl, grep

Как правильнее решить задачу:

Есть несколько (например 30) файлов, в каждом файле порядка 10 000 строк.
Каждая строка имеет своё ключевое слово.
В каких-то файлах есть строки с одинаковыми ключевыми словами.
Требуется вывести все строки которые встречаются в файлах n-раз.

P.S. В пределах одного файла ключевые слова тоже могут встречаться несколько раз, но это не считается. Само ключевое слово не известно (в том смысле что поиск по шаблону не подходит), все слова разделены одним разделителем, строчки также разделены.

Интересует вопрос реализации именно с точки зрения быстродействия.
 grep / perl / js - реализация алгоритма вторична

Comment: Надо как то конкретизировать понятие "ключевое слово".. А то например слов "the" в английском тексте много наберется и в итоге очень многие строки окажутся "похожими"

Comment: После того как определились что такое "ключевое слово" читаем все файлы, выделяем слова. Складываем в хеш с индексом по слову, элемент хеша то же хеш, индексируемый например по номеру файла, а в нем массив с номерами строк. Ну и дальше обходим все ключи хеша и считаем нужные нам показатели, либо кол-во файлов, либо как то количество строк где встретилось (определяемся что же такое "количество совпадений". Если слово "X" в одном файле было 3 раза, а в другом 2 раза, а в третьем 5 раз - то сколько совпадений засчитывается ?). после того как посчитали у нас на раках есть номера файлов и строк

Comment: ключевое слово - просто слово в строке, которое будет встречаться в других файлах. ну например - фамилия в анкетных данных. давайте даже упростим, "ключевое слово" в строке одно, дальше идут только ряды цифры через разделители. ... есть ощущение что пробег хешей не хилый такой будет

Comment: Совпадения засчитываются по кол-ву файлов в которых нашлось слово.  Условие неоднократного нахождения в файле ключевого слова - возможная ошибка на самом деле, в пределах одного файла все ключевые слова должны быть оригинальны, извиняюсь, излишне усложнил задачу

Comment: Т.е. грубо говоря мы берем _одно, строго определенное слово_ из строки и работаем по нему ... Это облегчает задачу. Но принцип тот же. Подсчет слов хешем самый быстрый способ. Тут просто он чуть усложнен, потому что придется хранить больше информации, дабы узнать где эти слова были. И у нас выходит одно полное сканирование всех файлов и одно сканирование хеша.

Comment: Ну последнее замечание еще больше упрощает задачу, тогда действительно, в хеше храним чуть ли не только сам счетчик. Правда требование распечатать потом все строки все равно заставляет сохранять информацию как минимум о местоположении строк. Как вариант конечно можно все строки загрузить в массив, добавив к строкам информацию о том из какого они файла и отсортировать этот массив. а дальше пробегаем массив и считаем идущие друг за другом строки с одинаковым словом.

Comment: Памяти оно конечно прилично сожрет. но каких то более быстрых методов мне в голову не приходит. И я бы лично это на перле делал. Он на такие штуки заточен. grep тут явно не помощник, он ищет конкретные шаблоны. js ... не знаю у кого хеши быстрее. Но у js все таки специализация немного другая.

Comment: И еще идейка ... Если _n_ достаточно большое число, то когда остается обработать менее _n_ файлов можно начать выбрасывать из хеша значения у которых счетчики уже заведомо не смогут достичь _n_ и главное, не включать в хеш новые значения, вообще.

Comment: быстрее у perl [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611037/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-40-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-go/611689#611689)